# Flutter - How to Set Text positon on a flexible width RaisedButton

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a RaiseButton With flexible width, its left and right space between screen is 20px. I want to set text position on this button. The text should placed 10px from button left edge. How to set?

padding: EdgeInsets.only(right:100) only set a fixed value.

```
            Positioned(
              child: RaisedButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 100),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print("click");
                  },
                  child: Text("Button", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12))),
              left: 10,
              right: 10,
              bottom: 200,
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps,

```
Center(
      child: Container(
        //provide your margin here
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
        height: 40,
        child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print("click");
        },
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),//provide your left padding here
            child: Text("Button", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)))),
      ),
    )
```